# Compare datetime field (for birthday) with today

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a datetime field to hold an individual's date of birth.

How can I write a query that returns all records where today is the individual's birthday?

Comment: you mean select all fields whose b'day is today ??

Comment: Please show what you've already tried and any errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare the month and day parts of the birthdate field to those from the current date:

```
select * from person 
where datepart("month", birthdate) = datepart("month", getdate()) 
and datepart("day", birthdate) = datepart("day", getdate())
```

[More information on DATEPART is here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the fields if today is their birthday by using Datepart function of SQLServer.

Using datepart you can get the date portions of the complete date like day, month and year.

Here you need to compare only day and month for checking whether today is birthday.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATEPART(d, @dob) = DATEPART(d, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(m, @dob) = DATEPART(m, GETDATE())
```

## [see demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/606b5/1)

Comment: +1 ..for answering it blindly and giving fiddle demo :D

Comment: @george >the question makes sense but op asked it unclearly..